# Filtering a column based on having some value in one of the rows in SQL or Presto Athena

Tags: sql, group-by, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying in Athena to output only users which have some specific value in them but not in all of the rows

Suppose I have the table below.
I want all users which have value '100' in at least one of their rows but also having in other rows value different than 100.

```
user | value

A    | 1

B    | 2

A    | 100

D    | 3

A    | 4

C    | 3

C    | 5

D    | 100
```

So in this example I would want to get only users A and D because only them having 100 and none 100.

I tried maybe grouping by user and creating an array of values per user and then checking if array contains 100 but I don't manage doing it presto.
Also I thought about converting rows to columns and then checking if one of columns equals 100.

Those solutions are too complex? Anybody knows how to implement them or anyone has a better simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

The users that have at least one value of 100 can be found with this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user
FROM some_table
WHERE value = 100
```

But I assume you are after all tuples of user and value where the user has at least one value of 100, this can be accomplished by using the query above in a slightly more complex query:

```
WITH matching_users AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT user
  FROM some_table
  WHERE value = 100
)
SELECT user, value
FROM matching_users
LEFT JOIN some_table USING (user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query as below to achieve your required output=

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE User IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT User
    FROM your_table
    WHERE Value = 100
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the users, I would go for aggregation:

```
select user
from t
group by user
having sum(case when value = 100 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If `100` is the maximum possible value, this can be simplified to:

```
having max(value) = 100
```